# Popup component renders but positioned off-page

Tags: reactjs, popup, tailwind-css

I've created a popup element using Tailwindcss.
Functionality-wise the popup renders and is removed totally fine but the problem is that the Popup component's properties are set to h-screen (height: 100%;) and if I'm scrolled down, the pop-up looks off.

For functionality, I've added a class to the body that prevents scrolling but the component is still rendered weirdly.

[Image for Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fiGqz.png)

Popup component code:

```js
interface OrderSummaryProps {
    renderOrderSummary: () => void;
    OrderSummaryPopupState: boolean;
}

// { cartList, renderPopUp }: OrderSummaryProps
function OrderSummary({ renderOrderSummary, OrderSummaryPopupState }: OrderSummaryProps) {
    const getBody = document.querySelector('body')

    if (OrderSummaryPopupState) getBody?.classList.add('overflow-hidden')
    else getBody?.classList.remove('overflow-hidden')

    return (
        <>
            <div className='absolute top-0 bg-black z-10 w-full backdrop-filter backdrop-blur-sm bg-opacity-25 flex justify-center items-center' style={{ height: '100%' }}>
                <div className='bg-white shadow-xl w-max h-max border border-neutral-200 rounded-xl flex items-center justify-between flex-col px-20 py-10'>
                    <div className='flex flex-col justify-center my-10'>
                        <button onClick={() => renderOrderSummary()} className='rounded-full py-2 px-6 border-2 border-red-200 bg-red-500 font-bold text-white'>סגור חלון</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    );
}

export default OrderSummary;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to that challenge was using wisely the 'fixed' and 'inset-0' tailwind properties. this has fixed the popup to the screen no matter where you're located in the page.

Just a tip for newbies like me - Codepen for front-end can be your best friend.

[Check out also Tailwind CSS Docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).